# How to create the cloud computing set up in our lab?

Tags: drupal, cloud, cloud-hosting

I am doing a research project with my friend on cloud computing. The project requires us to create a web application using Drupal(content management system) and deploy the same on our own private cloud set up. I knew there are some third parties(like amazon, google etc) that provide us cloud set-up. But, our project requires us to create our own cloud environment with the available servers in our lab. We are new to this topic and kind of help up. Any help on this topic would be greatly Appreciated.

Regards,
Sathish

Comment: Depends what you want from the 'cloud'. Hosting? Processing? Disk space? What you're describing sounds like a conventional load-balanced website.

Comment: @hoipolloi, Our project doesn't concentrate on solving big computational problems or something like that. Yes. We would be more interested in load balancing stuffs. We would like our application to be tested with 1000's of hits at the same time. Hope, I am clear this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use our free [Drupal AMIs](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) in Amazon EC2 and with Eucalyptus. If you'd prefer to, you can download VMWare images from the same page (they are also free).

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at the following pieces of software?

- [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/): Very easy to install using the [Ubuntu Enteprise Cloud](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC) distribution, offers the same API as AWS
- [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/): Never used it personally (but considering it for a future project), development started by the NASA, now deployed on different high-profile providers, such as [RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2011/03/08/rackspace-cloud-builders-supports-openstack-cloud-deployments/)

Comment: Thank you for the link . I will read about Eucalyptus and get back to you for any help. Do you have any idea like how much time it's gonna take to get the overall set-up? .

Comment: If everything works as expected, the time of two ubuntu installations. The main difficulties I've encountered had to do with IP assignment (DHCP/static/...). Check out this document http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusNetworkConfiguration_v2.0 for more information

Answer (score 0):

Eucalyptus and OpenStack are open source tools, you could set up private cloud with them, but will need time and effort. If you are not limited to use open source, try Nimbula Director 2.0 , this is a enterprise product to set up a private cloud that and is free to use up to 40 cores. Keep me posted on what you chose or if you found a better one.